# How to set Flutter text max length value?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using Flutter programming. I need to display a title and a button next to the title. If the text length is less button also should display next to the text. If text length is more i want to fix the text length as maximum 200px and need to show the button next to the title.

I am using the below code. And **working fine with the less text length**.

Problem is: If text length is more, then my button is moving out of screen. You can see the behaviour in the below attached image.

```
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: RichText(
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        strutStyle: StrutStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                        text: TextSpan(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), text: model.title),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Text("My Button"),
                  ],
                )
```

[image]

Comment: I have solved the problem with sub-string.  If string length is more than 16 chars then, i am taking substring which ends with ".." so finally while displaying it displays 16 characters+.. for the longs texts.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no `maxLength` property for `RichText` and `Text` widget. If you are using `RichText` class, you'll have `maxLines` property that can be used. I tried to recreated your case and wrapped `RichText` widget with `Flexible` widget that lets the child widget to use only the minimum available space. But I wasn't able to replicate the error you mentioned. The long text I used gets `ellipsis` and the `button` doesn't go out of the screen. Note that I also used `maxLines` property which if you set to 2, will wrap the long text in new line without moving away the `button` and the long text will be shown as `ellipsis`. Sample working code below:

```
body: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Flexible(
                  child: RichText(
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    strutStyle: StrutStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                    text: TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), text: 'I am using Flutter programming. I need to display a title and a button next to the title. If the text length is less button also should display next to the text. If text length is more i want to fix the text length as maximum 200px and need to show the button next to the title.'),
                  ),
                )

              ),

              Text("My Button"),
            ],
          )
        )
```

[image]

If you set `maxLines` to 1, the long text will wrap in ellipsis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have solved the issue with substring. If string length is more than 16 chars then, i am taking substring which ends with ".." so finally while displaying it displays 16 characters+.. for the longs texts. Appreciates for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can put maximum characters

```
text.substring(0,150)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String addressText = userAddress.address.toString();

   if(addressText.length > 22)
   addressText = addressText.substring(0,22);
```

You can check length and split string if exceeds max length.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Expanded or give fixed width to container of rich text, like this with Expanded widget:-

```
Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: RichText(
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  strutStyle: StrutStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), text: model.title),
                                ),
                              ),

                              Text("My Button"),
                            ],
                          )
```

Comment: If i give fixed size for container, my button is not near to text when text length is small. And Expanded already tried, no use incase if the text length is more. Same issue like i mentioned in my question attached image.

Comment: try by using (textAlign: TextAlign.right) for rich text and wrap Text('My Button') with Align widget and give (alignment: Alignment.centerLeft) to it. hope it will help to solve your problem

Comment: @manpereet, Thanks for your reply. i have solved the problem with text length. If string length is more than 16 chars then, i am taking substring which ends with ".." so finally while displaying it displays 16 characters+.. for the longs texts.